# Vue js quantity count in list

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a list of global products.

```
<span v-for="product in products">
   {{product.name}}
</span>
```

I also have sales which contain products.

```
<div v-for="sale in sales">
  <span v-for="product, key in sale.items">
   {{product.name}}
  </span>
</div>
```

This prints out a list of all attached products to this sale.

```
 Product #1
 Product #2
 Product #1
 Product #3
 Product #2
```

I want the above list, to display quantities, instead of repeating...like this.

```
 Product #1 x 2
 Product #2 x 2
 Product #3 x 1
```

So normally in regular javascript I might do.

```
 for(var i = 0 ; i<=products.length; i++){
   var qty = 0;
   for(var k =0; k<=sales.items.length; k++){
     if(sales.items[k].id==products[i].id){
       qty++;
     }
   }
   if(qty!=0){
      console.log(products[i].name+" x "+qty);
   }
 }
```

But how would I do this in vue.js?

I've tried

```
<div v-for="sale in sales">
 <span v-for="product in products">
   <span v-for="prod in sales.items" v-if="product.id==prod.id">
       {{product.name}} x {{how do I get quantity here??}}
   </span>
 </span>
</div>
```

Obviously thats not gonna work, cuz I need a quantity variable that resets on each loop around the products.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom `methods` for that:

```
 <span v-for="product in products" :key="product.id">
     {{product.name}} x {{ getProductQuanlity(product.id) }}
 </span>


methods: {
  getProductQuanlity (productId) {
    var qty = 0;
    for(var k =0; k <= this.sales.items.length; k++){
     if(this.sales.items[k].id == productId){
       qty++;
     }
    }
    return qty

  }
}
```

Comment: This will display each instance of the product, but it appears the desired behavior is to only display it once with the number of times it occurs.

Comment: I thought each product only display 1 time with its quantity, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, so what is ensuring each product is counted once in this code?

Comment: Normally `product` is unique in `products` array (by `product.id`). `getProductQuanlity ` is called only 1 time for each product.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but the question suggests that the products in `sales.items` _do_ have duplicates. This answer is iterating over `products` which is (presumably) unique.

Comment: It's similar with normal javascript solution which @KyleK has posted in his question. Loop through `products` and display its quantity.

Answer (score 0):

Create a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) to use for your `v-for`:

```
var app = new Vue({
  ...
  computed: {
    // a computed getter
    productSubtotals: function () {
      var subtotals = {};
      for (var i = 0; i < this.sale.items.length; i++) {
          subtotals [arr[i]] = 1 + (subtotals[arr[i]] || 0);
      }
      return subtotals; //A list of product/count pairs may be a more appropriate data structure
    }
  }
})
```

And the HTML:

```
<div v-for="sale in sales">
  <span v-for="(total, product) in productSubtotals">
    {{product.name}}: {{total}}
  </span>
</div>
```

You can also add a setter if required.